# How to use a user variable in 'USE database' statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make the name of my MYSQL database variable, so it can be set from the outside (a python script) to whatever I like. Thus avoiding hardcoding the name of the database.

I tried passing the name via defining a user variable in the mysql client and then loading the sql script. I was able to create the database but not to connect to it via the `USE` statement

**Definition of variable** and **calling the sql script**:

```
mysql> SET @database_name = 'name';
mysql> SOURCE script.sql;
```

Code of **script.sql**:

```
-- creating database according to user variable
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ', @database_name, ' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- selecting the database according to the user variable
SET @query = CONCAT('USE ', @database_name);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I expected that this would work, but unexpectedly MYSQL threw this error into my face:

```
This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

The problem is, that there are a lot of table defintions in this script, and they all need the actual database name in front of them, or the `USE` statement has to work, so the correct database is selected and no database name is needed when creating the tables.

I am grateful for any useful tips, thank you :).

Comment: You know that you can use the database name in SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries like this? `SELECT * FROM <database_name>.<table_name> ` then you will not have to use `USE <database_name>` like you already said i think that is your only workaround.. Or the more logical one place the USE in the .sql file.

Comment: The issue is, that I use `CREATE TABLE` and there it is not valid, sadly.

Comment: The creation of the database works, I never said it doesnt work. As I said, the issue is the `USE` statement. I wanted to connect to the data base, so I can create tables without having to give the database name, because that requires even more prepared statements, and I want to avoid prepared statements for all of the table creations.

Comment: "The creation of the database works, I never said it doesnt work" Yes i removed the comment i need some coffee badly...

Comment: according to [manual 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html#idm140517939143040) nor `CREATE SCHEMA` nor `USE` are supported by prepared statement ... -> Why prepared statement? (why not "just execute"?)

Comment: ...but/and: `CREATE DATABASE` is supported by prepared statement, and (in mysql) it is "equivalent"  to `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Comment: @xerx593 I already know all of this. I tried leaving out the `PREPARE` but that doesn't work either. As stated the prepared statement `USE`, not the `CREATE DATABASE/SCHEMA` bit, fails to execute.

Answer (score 0):

A "complex" workaround might be to generate a `.sql` file if you have `FILE` privilege and the [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable is set also [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) also might to be changed.

```
# SET SESSION max_allowed_packet = '<>'; commented because it might be needed to generate larger .sql file 

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(sql_lines.line SEPARATOR ';');
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ', @database_name, 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1') AS line
  UNION 
  SELECT CONCAT('USE ', @database_name) AS line
) AS sql_lines
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @database_name = '<test>'
) AS init_user_param 
INTO
 DUMPFILE '<absolute_file_path>';

SOURCE script.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you can generate the sql like you were typing it on the sql prompt.  You could write everything like you are typing it, but using a bash script:

Code like this (filename: generate-database.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

mydatabase="mytest";

cat << EOF
create database $mydatabase;
use $mydatabase;
create table test1 (id int);
create table test2 (id int);

EOF
```

You can even pass the database name as the first parameter if you want to have a database for a different site.  Then you would do something like this:

```
bash generate-database.sh | mysql -u <username> -p
```

Then that will do everything like you would do as if you were typing it in mysql.

To pass in as the first parameter you would do this:

```
mydatabase=$1;
```

On the command prompt you would do this:

```
bash generate-database.sh MarkTownsend | mysql -u <username> -p
```